# How do you make a progress bar for file upload progress?

Tags: php, file, progress-bar

Hey guys i'm making a file upload and i can't figure out how i would make a progress bar for it. Does anyone have a resource or reference page which i can look at or even better some source code that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options. Try [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), a jQuery plugin for upload progress bars. Specifically, the [download](http://www.uploadify.com/download/) includes a PHP example.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this:

http://www.uploadify.com/

It is easy to use jquery and php uploading method. you can upload multiple files at a time.
plus you can view their upload progress through a progress bar.

its easy to integerate. the link includes documentation and demo.

here is another link to a beautiful GUI Ajax uploader:

http://www.plupload.com/

You would love it. just browse for and select files to upload. it shows there progress while uploading.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dont forget to view plup examples. it also offers extensive customization features.

http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php